# How Arrays.binarySearch() works without sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search

I am curious to know what is the logic behind the answer I am getting when I am using Arrays.binarySearch without sorting.

```
int d[]={6,-4,12,0,-10};
int x=12;
int y=Arrays.binarySearch(d,x);

   System.out.println(y);
```

Output:2

I am preparing for a contest of java in which such rare cases are raised , so i asked this question.Please help with any possible solution.

Comment: The result is unpredicatble. Your array MUST be sorted.

Comment: Read the doc . It clearly states : _"The array must be sorted (as by the sort(int[]) method)"_

Comment: Or is it that the binarySearch could find the answer in the middle in the first pass itself so it never got to know whether the array is sorted or not.

Comment: That's probably what happened, yes. The method doesn't *check* that the array is sorted. It *assumes* that it is sorted. If it isn't sorted, you could get a correct result, an incorrect result, an exception, an infinite loop, or anything else: the result is undefined.

Comment: @JBNizet: Actually no exceptions and no infinite loop in case of the Java implementation. Only right or wrong answers. See my answer below.

Comment: @JohannesH.: agreed. But you base that on the current implementation. I base it on the defined contract of the method, specified in the javadoc. It doesn't guarantee anything if the array is not sorted. Whatever the way you look at it, the result is the same: it's a bug to invoke this method with an unsorted array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Java API reference, `if it is not sorted, the results are undefined.`

In your case, you got lucky: binary search is "divide and conquer".
The algorithm looks at the middle of the array. If it is the number, it returns (was the case in your example - that's why it worked).
 If the element is bigger than the one you search for, repeat with the left part (the ones with the lower nubmers). Otherwise use the right one.
Repeat until you found the element. If you have only 1 element left, and it's not the element you searched for, the element is not in that array. In case of the Java implementation, it just returns the index of the last element that was found (which happens to be `i(-(insertion point) - 1)`)

Comment: One thing to add: if the array has an even number of elements (so there is no middle element), the lower one is taken. Calculate the middle element like so: (length - 1) / 2

Answer (score 4):

You got lucky. The Java implementation requires the array to be sorted for it to guarantee a correct answer:

> The array must be sorted (as by the sort(int[]) method) prior to
>   making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could get anything. Reading the javadocs for [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte%5B%5D%2C%20byte%29)

> The array must be sorted (as by the sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

now the [**javadocs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) states that

> The array **must be sorted** (as by the sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the **results are undefined**. If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found.